# SearchView Filter items inside RecyclerView with a SearchView

Tags: android, android-fragments, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a fragment where I have implemented a recyclerView. In the layout of the fragment, I added a SearchView to filter the items. Filtering works well; the problem arises when I try to delete a few letters or even the whole word from the searchview. In fact, it should return the list of the recyclerView, but it does not.

FragmentListapazienti

```
private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"; //numero di colonne
private int mColumnCount = 1; //n° colonne inizializzato a 1
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener; //interfaccia per comunicare con il fragment
AdapterPazienti adapter;
DBHelper dbHelper;
SearchView ricercaPaz;



public FragmentListaPazienti() {
}

// TODO: Customize parameter initialization
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static FragmentListaPazienti newInstance(int columnCount) {
    FragmentListaPazienti fragment = new FragmentListaPazienti();
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); //salva in un bundle il parametro (nel nostro caso è un intero)
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        //verifica che ci sono argomenti passati tramite il metodo setArguments. Se getArguments
        //non è nullo, allora prendo questi argomenti e setto la variabile mColumnCount
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_pazienti, container, false);
    /*ricercaPaz =  view.findViewById(R.id.srcPaziente);
    ricercaPaz.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.filter(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

    }); */


    // Set the adapter
    //if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        //verifica che ci sia il recycler view dentro fragment_itel_list (layout)
        Context context = view.getContext(); //serve per poi poter chiamare i metodi della classe context
        //Context è il contesto che contiene il fragment; nel nostro caso il context è l'activity
        //Nei parametri successivi in cui c'è context, avrei potuto mettere this.activity, ma poichè questo
        //fragmente potrà essere utilizzato da più activity, allora context dipende dall'activity
        //a cui è "attached" il fragment: ce lo dice view.getContext
        //RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            //se ho una colonna, il layout sarà lineare, altrimenti sarà grid
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        Sessione sessione = new Sessione(context);
        String mailUtente = sessione.getSessione();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.datiPaziente(mailUtente);
        Pazienti.ITEMS.clear();
        Pazienti lista = new Pazienti();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            lista.addItem(new Pazienti.PazientiItem(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5)));
        }
        //Invece di scrivere la riga qui sopra, avrei potuto farlo così:
        adapter = new AdapterPazienti(lista.ITEMS, mListener); //o Pazienti.ITEMS
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //}
    ricercaPaz =  view.findViewById(R.id.srcPaziente);
    ricercaPaz.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.filter(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.filter(newText);
            return true;
        }

    });
    return view;
}


//Dobbiamo controllare ora che la MainActivity abbia implementato l'interfaccia, altrimenti non
//potrebbe comunicare con il fragment. Guardo allora se la mia activity context ha implementato
//OnLIstFragmentInteractionListener. Se lo ha implementato, allora per il polimorfismo context sarà
//anche un'istanza di OnLIstFragmentInteractionListener. Allora associo a mListener, l'istanza
//della mia activity. Altrimenti lancia un'eccezione.
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onListFragmentInteraction(Pazienti.PazientiItem item); //questo metodo dovrà essere implementato dalla MainActivity
    // che dovrà dire cosa fare in caso di pressione di un item della lista. DummyItem è l'oggetto che ha il
    // contenuto di un singolo item della lista
}
```

Adapter

```
private List<Pazienti.PazientiItem> mValues; //lista da cui prendere i dati
private final FragmentListaPazienti.OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener; //istanza dell'interfaccia
//Noi vogliamo che quando il View Holder venga toccato, allora devo chiamare il metodo onListFragmentInteraction,
//che è quello descritto nell'interfaccia OnListFragmentInteractionListener, definita in ItemFragment, e
//ci dice cosa fare in caso di click.

public AdapterPazienti(List<Pazienti.PazientiItem> items, FragmentListaPazienti.OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items; // la nostra lista
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.singolo_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mNomeView.setText(mValues.get(position).nome);
    holder.mCognomeView.setText(mValues.get(position).cognome);
    holder.mData.setText(mValues.get(position).data);

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ((v): lumped, modo ancora più concentrato di scrivere la classe anonima
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView mNomeView;
    public final TextView mCognomeView;
    public final TextView mData;
    public Pazienti.PazientiItem mItem; //dato che inseriremo nel ViewHolder

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mNomeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomePaziente);
        mCognomeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cognomePaziente);
        mData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dataPaziente);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mCognomeView.getText() + "'";
    }
}

public void filter(String text) {
    Pazienti lista = new Pazienti();
    if(text.isEmpty()){
        lista.ITEMS.clear();
        lista.ITEMS.addAll(mValues);
    } else{
        ArrayList<Pazienti.PazientiItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(Pazienti.PazientiItem item: mValues){
            if(item.nome.toLowerCase().contains(text) || item.cognome.toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                result.add(item);
            }
        }
        lista.ITEMS.clear();
        lista.ITEMS.addAll(result);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

DummyContent-DummyItem --> Pazienti-PazientiItem

```
public static final List<PazientiItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<PazientiItem>();


public static void addItem(PazientiItem item) {
    //aggiungo un item alla lista
    ITEMS.add(item);
}




public static class PazientiItem {
    //Qui descrivo il contenuto del dato
    public final String nome;
    public final String cognome;
    public final String data;
    public final String mail;
    public final String telefono;


    public PazientiItem(String nome, String cognome, String data, String mail, String telefono) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.data = data;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return cognome;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586592/recyclerview-list-search-filter-edittext-problem/69593988#69593988) I think this will answer your question.

Comment: @BroscR thank u. I tried to use the code you recommended but it still doesn't work. Now it doesn't even search for items.